# how to properly use numpy.zeros in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm studying machine learning and I found this code in github, but I'm having some problems to make it work correctly, and I also do not have experience with python which is not making things much easier hahaha

> filhos =  np.zeros( (n_filhos, n_vars) ) is returning this error:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\GitHub\evoman_framework\optimization_individualevolution_demo.py",
>   line 272, in 
>       filhos = cruzamento(pop)  # crossover   File "D:\GitHub\evoman_framework\optimization_individualevolution_demo.py",
>   line 171, in cruzamento
>       filhos =  np.zeros( (n_filhos, n_vars) ) TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

```
############################################################################### 
# EvoMan FrameWork - V1.0 2016                                    #
# DEMO : Neuroevolution - Genetic Algorithm with perceptron neural network.   #
# Author: Karine Miras                                                #
# karine.smiras@gmail.com                                         #
############################################################################### 

# imports framework
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'evoman') 
from environment import Environment
from controller import Controller

# imports other libs 
import time
import numpy as np
from math import fabs,sqrt
import glob, os

# genetic algorithm params

run_mode = 'train' # train or test
stateread = None # 'state_1' 
statesave = 'state_1'
n_vars = (env.get_num_sensors()+1)*5  # perceptron
#n_vars = (env.get_num_sensors()+1)*10 + 11*5  # multilayer with 10 neurons
#n_vars = (env.get_num_sensors()+1)*50 + 51*5 # multilayer with 50 neurons
dom_u = 1
dom_l = -1
npop = 100
gens = 30
mutacao = 0.2
last_best = 0

# crossover
def cruzamento(pop):

    total_filhos = np.zeros((0,n_vars))


    for p in range(0,pop.shape[0], 2):       
        p1 = torneio(pop)
        p2 = torneio(pop)

        n_filhos =   np.random.randint(1,3+1, 1) 
        filhos =  np.zeros( (n_filhos, n_vars) )

        for f in range(0,n_filhos): 

            cross_prop = np.random.uniform(0,1)
            filhos[f] = p1*cross_prop+p2*(1-cross_prop)

            # mutation 
            for i in filhos[f]:
                if np.random.uniform(0 ,1)<=mutacao:
                    filhos[f][i] =   filhos[f][i]+np.random.normal(dom_l, dom_u)

            filhos[f] = np.array(map(lambda y: limites(y), filhos[f]))           

            total_filhos = np.vstack((total_filhos, filhos[f]))

    return total_filhos
```

Comment: Too much code, please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: reduced, thanks for the tips ,trying to keep minimal now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because your `n_filhos` or `n_vars` type is not an integer. I can run only the first variable separately and it returns the array.

```
>>> n_filhos = np.random.randint(1,3+1, 1) 
>>> n_filhos
array([3])
```

Check the type of them partly before the running.

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.randint(1,3+1, 1)` returns an array, not an integer. Dimension specification expects the tuple of integers. Instead, there's a tuple of numpy array and an integer:

```
>>> np.random.randint(1,3+1, 1)
array([2])
```